# Retrieving my posts from firebase and display it on my collectionView Cells? ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
getImageUrl()
}


func getImageUrl(){
ref.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapchot) in
    let postsss = snapchot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
    for (_,posst) in postsss {
        if let uid = posst["userID"] as? String{

            if uid == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid{
                if let myPostURL = posst["pathToImage"] as? String{
                self.imageURLs.append(myPostURL)

                }

            }
        }
    }
} 
}
```

I want my code to go through all the posts on Firebase and then check if their userID matches the currentusers uid, if they matched which means they are my images. then send the URL in `pathToImage` to an array in my code called imageURLs()[ "" ].but I don't know how to to that??. I am using SDWebImage to display my images to the collectionView cell. i have tested it and it works fine if i copy and paste a random URL in the array called imageURLs[ "URL here" ]

I am very new to Swift and Firebase, so any help would be greatly appreciated!! :)

HERE IS AN IMAGE OF MY FIREBASE FILES.
https://ibb.co/bXLMcb

Psst! posts/pathToImage holds the URL so that's the one i want to retrieve.

users/urlToImage is just a profile picture. i don't really need it right now

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please explain where exactly is the problem you are having. Are you seeing error messages?

Comment: Just a hunch, but at very least, your "posst" keys for userID and pathToImage don't match what you used in your firebase database and will cause problems...

Comment: It's generally a bad practice to name your variables the same word with different spellings. This probably has something to do with the unexpected behavior that you're seeing.

Comment: here is what I want my code to do, I want it to go through all the posts on Firebase and then check if their userID matches the currentusers uid, if they matched which means they are my images. then send the URLs of the image to an array in my code called imageURLs()[ "" ].but I don't know how to to that??.  I am using SDWebImage to display my images to the collectionView cell. i have tested it and it works fine if i copy and paste a random URL in the array called imageURLs[ "URL here" ].  like i said i am very new to programming :D

Comment: Not sure about this question; If you want to go through the posts to see which ones belong to this uid then a simple solution is to query the posts for ones where userID = this userId. That query will just return the posts for this uid. As the results are returned, add the urls to your dataSource Array. Or am I missing something?

Comment: actually thats is what I want, but how do I write this in code?? - Jay

Comment: You're iterating over every posts node in your database and that's going to take a while. You're going to want to query for the users posts you want by their uid - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To locate specific data within a node a Query is used.

While iterating over the nodes works, if there's a million nodes it's going to take a long time and tie  up the UI while waiting for that to happen.

The bottom line is; if you know what you are looking for - in this case a uid - then a query is a super simple solution.

```
let postsRef = self.ref.child("posts")
let query = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "userID").queryEqual(toValue: "uid_0")
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        for child in snapshot.children { //.value can return more than 1 match
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
            let myPostURL = dict["urlToImage"] as! String
            self.imageURLs.append(myPostURL)
        }

    } else {
        print("no user posts found")
    }
}
```

With the above code, we first create a reference to our posts node. Then a query that will only return this users (uid_0) posts.

We then iterate over the snapshot of posts and add them to the array.

This is much more efficient that loading and evaluating every node in the database.

See [Sorting And Filtering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data) data for more information.

Comment: This is a pretty elegant solution! This avoids any indexing or double calls to firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about storing an index of all your users posts somewhere in your database. That way you don't need to observe all posts every time. This is called denormalization. Firebase has an article in their docs about organizing your database.

[Here's some information regarding firebase filtering in swift](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#filtering_data).

The best solution is to add a separate node that has a list of "post IDs" organized by user. Then you could observe that node, and only download each post specifically by the returned ID.  [Here's a link about flattening data structures in firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#flatten_data_structures). It would look something like this.

```
"posts":{
    "somePostID":{
        "timestamp": "0200231023",
        "postContent": "here's my post content",
        "authorUID" : "0239480238402934"
     } ...
},
"postsByGivenUID":{
    "someAuthorID":{
        "somePostID": "true",
        "somePostID": "true",
    },
    "someOtherAuthorID":{
        "somePostID": "true",
        "somePostID": "true",
        "somePostID": "true"
    }
}
```

This is actually a much bigger problem than just changing how you structure your code. For scalability sake, you're going to have to reevaluate how you structure the data in firebase altogether.

Then, you can nest your firebase query, sort of like this:

```
ref.child("postByGivenUID").child("Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
    ref.child("posts").child(snapshot.value).observeSingleEventOfType(of: .value) { (snap) in
        // your actual post data will be here
        // that way you won't be downloadin ALL posts EVERY time

    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this answer makes sense; what are your querying for and why does the order matter? Wouldn't it make more sense to just query for posts that contain the uid? This answer is pretty close, just need to fix the code a bit.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the answer. I removed the query ordering and added a paragraph about denormalization

Comment: Closer. Think about what the OP is actually trying to do; query for all posts from a user by their user id. Suppose you have a million users - with the current code in your answer, you're iterating through a million nodes to try to find the 10 you are interested in. How about just performing a query for all of the nodes where uid = this users uid? That would then just return the 10 you want.

Comment: @Jay take a look at what I wrote. I added a bunch of detail and some examples.

Comment: @suley Well, while this works it's really not a good solution. Take into consideration (as I mentioned above) where there are a million posts. This method will have to load in and evaluate every post in the database - not only is that going to take a long time but it will have to happen as the user sits and waits for that to occur - with a slow connection it could take minutes or longer. A much simpler  solution is to query for the nodes you want; that will retrieve the specific data you are looking for, be very fast, and you only have to deal with small amount of data.

Comment: Also, using .childAdded here is going to cause a problem as that leaves an observer on every single node in the database and while you waiting 10 minutes to get the data you want, if something is added to any of those nodes, it's going to fire the .child added event again. Lastly *There's no amount of filtering that will allow you to only query for a specific value.* is completely incorrect as you can easily query for specific value in Firebase and Swift. See my answer for a correct solution

Comment: If you take a look at the reference, it's not pointed to every post. It's only pointed to a current users list of posts by ID. It won't queue up every post on the database. If you're using a table view, using .childAdded combined with reloading the tableView can make your tableview update every time a new post is made. This could be good or bad depending on the intended use.